# Connecting to Samba NAS from another Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, server, samba, share, file

I've setup a NAS Samba server for my Uni project, and I'm able to access all of the files from my Windows PC.

However, I want to try access the NAS from another Raspberry Pi. I got to 'Go>Network>WORKGROUP' and nothing comes up, other than an error saying:

"Failed to retrieve share list from server > The specified location is not mounted".

I'm still a nooby when it comes to all of this stuff. Is there a SIMPLE explanation on how I can connect another Raspberry Pi to my setup NAS?

Comment: Have you tried `mount`ing it from the command line?

Comment: I'm not too sure what this means? (I'm a complete no brain to this stuff!)

Comment: This is probably not difficult, but we need more information to help. Do you know the IP address of your Samba server? And the share name?